# Passing value between two angular 2 component typescript files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have two components that are not parent Components and those are child components but I need to pass data from component A to component B.
example:
component A.ts has an array of data 
example :

```
my data [
   {'name':'some a','email':'some a@gmail.com','grades':{}},
   {'name':'some b','email':'some b@gmail.com','grades':{}}
  ]
```

need to pass that my data to component B.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they don't have a parent/child relationship, the best way is a shared service [injected](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) into the constructors of A and B.

#### component A:

```
constructor(private sharingService: SharingService) { }

public myArray = [];

func() {
    ...
    this.sharingService.save(this.myArray);
}
```

#### Service:

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
constructor() {}

private array = [];

save(array) {
    this.array = array;
}

fetch() {
    return this.array;
}
```

#### component B:

```
constructor(private sharingService: SharingService) { }

public yourArray = this.sharingService.fetch();
```

[There's a good tutorial on services and component interaction on the Angular site](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Comment: I am able to send data to save method but this data is not getting in fetch method it displays like undefined.

Comment: could you add the code you're using (or better yet, a plunkr)?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some suggestions from @Sasha

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of @Lying Cake. You should use the service inorder to share the data between two independent components. 
The problem of undefined that you are facing is because you are calling the fetch method in the constructor. And you have not defined array value here: `private array`. So, it is giving undefined. Either define the initial value or remove the fetch method from the constructor and call only when the array value is not `undefined`.